# Mysql Return true if idx exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that returns true if the same idx exists in another table.

Here is what I want to do.

Two Tables:

```
User (user_idx, name)
Group (group_idx, user_idx)
```

Pseudo Query:

```
SELECT user_idx, name, (True(1)/False(0) value) as has_joined_group
FROM User
WHERE (Check if user_idx exists in Group table where group_idx is 3)
```

Can this be done using Mysql? If yes, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select column as true / false if id is exists in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284986/select-column-as-true-false-if-id-is-exists-in-another-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_idx, u.name, g.user_idx IS NOT NULL AS has_joined_group
FROM User AS u
LEFT JOIN Group AS g
ON g.user_idx = u.user_idx AND g.group_idx = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    u.user_idx,
    u.name, 
    CASE WHEN g.user_idx IS NOT NULL AND g.group_idx = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_joined_group
FROM 
    user u JOIN LEFT group g ON u.user_idx = g.user_idx
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.user_idx, u.name, if(g.user_idx IS NOT NULL,'true','false') as  has_joined_group
FROM User AS u
LEFT JOIN Group AS g
ON g.user_idx = u.user_idx AND g.group_idx = 3
```