# select column as true / false if id is exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, one for members and another one for their services.
Those are InnoDB tables on MySQL 5.6 server.

Members table:

```
id     |       name       |   phone
----------------------------------------
  1       Daniel             123456789
  2       Liam               123456789
  3       Lucas              123456789
```

Services table:

```
 MID    |    profile    |     lastSeen
----------------------------------------
  1       2                  2014-08-13 14:23:23
  3       1                  2014-08-12 15:29:11
```

I try to achieve this result:

```
 id     | name      | services
---------------------------------
  1       Daniel      true
  2       Liam        false
  3       Lucas       true
```

So if the user ID is exists in services table, the column services will be true or false otherwise.

I tried to do it with JOINs and Sub-Queries without success, so I need your help ;)

Comment: Can you show us your attempts? You might be almost there already.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` Services table, Try this query

```
SELECT members.id, members.name, 
       IF(services.mid IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) as services
FROM members
LEFT JOIN services ON (members.id = services.mid)
```

Comment: What if there are multiples rows in the services table?

Answer (score 3):

```
select m.id, m.name, case when s.mid is null then false else true end
from members m
left join services s
    on s.profile = m.id
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple query like this

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.name
    IF(s.MID,true,false) services
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN services s ON s.profile = m.id
```