# Add attribute to ActiveRecord_Relation results based on existence of relationship?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `users` table, a `notifications` table, and a join table of `notification_reads`. I'm trying to write a scope for an ActiveRecord query that will return all of the notifications (`Notification.all`) with an additional field based on whether the user has a correlating notification_read for that notification.

I'm imagining it would look something like:

```
class Notification
  scope :with_reads_by_user, -> (user) {
    select("*", "[some sql that produces a boolean] as read")
    .joins(:notification_reads)
      .where(notification_reads: {user: user})
  }
end
```

Nothing I've tried has seemed to come close, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one,

```
scope :by_user, lambda { |user|
       joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN notification_reads ON notification_reads.user_id = ? and notification_reads.notification_id = notifications.id", user.id).select("*", "IF(notification_reads.user_id IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) as is_read_by_user")
    }
```

Query

```
Notification.by_user(current_user)
```

Ref: [select column as true / false if id is exists in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284986/select-column-as-true-false-if-id-is-exists-in-another-table)

P.S: Not tried this.